# Заполнение полей input

Tags: javascript, html

У меня 70 текстовых полей. Значения в этих полях должны быть или 1 или -1. Суть состоит в том, что при нажатии Q (1) или E (-1), в первое поле должно ввестись значение, а фокус переходит на следующее поле. И так заполняются все 70 полей.  Добился только того, что я могу заполнять первое поле. Код:

```
<html>
<HEAD>

<script>    
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {   
    if (event.keyCode == 90)
        document.getElementById("pole").value = "1" 
    else
       document.getElementById("pole").value = "-1" 

  });
</script>

</HEAD>
<body>

<form action="0">
 <input id="pole" type="text" >
 <input id="pole2" type="text" >
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

В интернете уже искал, есть только частные случаи. Но решения так и не смог добиться. Просьба не закидывать меня ссылками - мол, читай - я уже все прошарил.

Comment: А вы в курсе, что keyCode 90 - это латинская заглавная Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта события `event` есть свойство `target`, которое возвращает элемент, вызвавший данное событие. Пользуясь этим, мы можем каждый раз получать текущий элемент, в который только что ввели значение. После того, как мы ввели значение, нам нужно переключиться на следующий элемент. Для этого у элементов есть свойство `nextElementSibling`, которое вернет следующий элемент, если он существует, либо `null`, если нет. Чтобы перевести фокус, на элемент вызывается метод `focus()`.

В дополнение, при обработке события ввода я бы использовал `keypress` вместо `keydown`, т.к. он не будет реагировать на спец клавиши вроде `Shift`, при условии что вам нужно вводить заглавные `Q` и `E`. Вызов `event.preventDefault()` необходим для того, чтобы в поле не попадал сам вводимый символ (`Q` или `E`), а оставались только значения `1` и `-1`.

Итого:

```
addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentInput = event.target;

    if (event.keyCode == 90) {
        currentInput.value = "1";
    } else {
        currentInput.value = "-1";
    }

    var nextInput = currentInput.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextInput) {
        nextInput.focus();
    }
});
```

Поиграться с кодом можно здесь: http://jsbin.com/hitunoqexi/1/

Свойство `nextElementSibling` и метод `preventDefault()` могут не поддерживаться в старых версиях IE, тогда придется использовать [полифилы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549031/1573638).

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```js
var pole_index = 0;

addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 69) {
    document.getElementById("pole" + pole_index).value = "-1"
    pole_index++;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 81) {
    document.getElementById("pole" + pole_index).value = "1"
    pole_index++;
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="0">
  <input id="pole0" type="text" />
  <input id="pole1" type="text" />
</form>
```

Проверку на лимит input`ов сделаете сами.